# Apagar somente se houver - na palavra

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-select, delete

Gostaria de deletar alguns registros inúteis do meu banco de dados

São eles, exemplo:
-2046820062
-2046820165
-2046820183

Resumindo, todos os registros que inicie com o simbolo - (menos) da minha coluna data2

Exemplo:
[image: delete]

ja tentei algo como:

```
DELETE SUBSTRING_INDEX(data2, '-', 1) FROM tabela
```

mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Essa coluna `data2` é de que tipo?

Comment: a coluna é int(11)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DELETE FROM tabela WHERE data2 LIKE '-%'

Comment: funciou também, obrigado <3

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
DELETE FROM tabela
WHERE CAST(data2 AS SIGNED) < 0
```

Veja o fiddle clicando [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2ab98d673fb3dda2d8e2f21d8498aaf).

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado =D